# Как решить проблему с переводом категорий в мультиязычном сайте на wordpress?

Tags: php, html, wordpress, функции, плагин

Есть мультиязычный (русский, английский языки) сайт на **wordpress** с установленным плагином [Polylang](https://ru.wordpress.org/plugins/polylang/). В целом, все переводит хорошо, но есть с ним одна проблемка: несмотря на то, что категории имеют привязку и переведены на оба языка - в меню при используемом на сайте русском название категории (Business) и ссылка при переходе на Посмотреть все ведет на англоязычную версию категории
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]
Код в консоли

```
<span class="featured-header-category">Категории: Market<a class="view-all" href="http://site.ru/en/category/market/">Посмотреть все</a></span>
```

код **function.php**

```
function paperback_menu_category_query() {

  $post_type = get_option( 'paperback_category_menu_edd', 'post' );
  $term_html = '';
  $output    = '';
  $id        = ( ! empty( $_REQUEST['id' ] ) ) ? $_REQUEST['id'] : '';

  if ( class_exists( 'Easy_Digital_Downloads' ) && 'download' === $post_type ) {
    $taxonomy = 'download_category';
  } else {
    $taxonomy = 'category';
  }

  if ( ! empty( $id ) ) {
    $term = get_term( (int) $id, $taxonomy );
  }

  if ( ! empty( $term ) && ! is_wp_error( $term ) ) {

    $args = apply_filters( 'paperback_mega_menu_query_args', array(
      'posts_per_page' => '6',
      'post_type'      => (array) $post_type,
      'post_status'    => 'publish',
      'tax_query'      => array(
        array(
          'taxonomy' => $taxonomy,
          'field'    => 'term_id',
          'terms'    => (int) $id
        )
      )
    ) );

    $posts = new WP_Query( $args );

    if ( $posts->have_posts() ) {
      ob_start();
      while( $posts->have_posts() ) {
        $posts->the_post();
        include( 'template-parts/content-mini-grid-item.php' );
      }
      $output = ob_get_clean();

      // Get category title and link
      $term_html = sprintf( esc_html__( 'Category: %s', 'paperback' ), $term->name ) . sprintf( wp_kses( __( '<a class="view-all" href="%s">View All</a>', 'paperback' ), array( 'a' => array( 'href' => array(), 'class' => 'view-all' ) ) ), esc_url( get_term_link( $term->term_id, $taxonomy ) ) );
    } else {
      $term_html = esc_html__( 'No articles were found.', 'paperback' );
    }
  }

  wp_send_json( array(
    'html'      => $output,
    'term_html' => $term_html
  ) );

}
add_action( 'wp_ajax_paperback_category', 'paperback_menu_category_query' );
add_action( 'wp_ajax_nopriv_paperback_category', 'paperback_menu_category_query' );
```

Установка дополнения [polylang-slug](https://github.com/grappler/polylang-slug) не решило проблему - категории (рубрики) с одинаковым слагом не устанавливаются, а накладываются друг на друга.
Как можно это решить?

Comment: Не по теме, но с WPML таких проблем не возникает.

Comment: @KAGGDesign, одинаковый слаг в ВП? Это ж не реально (ну почти не реально - как-то можно, но это старшнючий  и ненадёжный костыль)

Comment: @SeVlad а где про одинаковый слаг? Я такого не писал

Comment: @KAGGDesign, про одинаковый слаг сам вопрос/задача ТСа :)

Comment: @KAGG Design я выше ссылку на плагин сбрасывал `polylang-slug`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Нашел ответ - очень банальный. Инфа подтягивалась с главного меню, а там были указаны англоязычные ссылки с русским переводом. Корректировка на русскоязычные ссылки в меню решило проблему